# Rails PG form values being sent null to db despite ":name, null: false" being set

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, postgresql

**ANSWER:** Thanks to Deepak in the comments, I forgot to add Model level validations as well. These are done with `validates :name, presence: true`

My rails app decided to accept null values to the PG database for some reason that I cannot pick up.

Order migration file:

```
create_table :orders do |t|
  t.string :name, null: false
  t.string :company
  t.string :email, null: false
  t.string :event_type, null: false
  t.string :country, null: false
  t.text :description, null: false

  t.timestamps
end
```

My order_controller.rb

```
private
def order_params
params.require(:order).permit(:name, :company, :email, :event_type,
:country, :description)
end
```

With my create action.

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
if @order.save
   redirect_to root_path
else
```

It is redirecting to the root_path of the home screen with this being send to the controller.

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"longlongtoken",
 "order"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "company"=>"",
 "event_type"=>"", "country"=>"", "description"=>""}, 
 "commit"=>"Create Order"}`
```

All actions in my `new.html.erb` file follow this basic pattern

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label "Email*"%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "X"%>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add model level validations as well

Comment: appreciate the quick reply, i just came back to rails and completely forgot about that!

Comment: when you added `null: false` in migration, after running migration once ? can you post relevant part of schema.rb file

Comment: @Tachyons that was the relevant part, I just needed model level validations if you read above (: